# Using ansible_host to lookup hostvars value, but looping thru list fails

Tags: ansible

I've using a hostvars value to decide what my mount path is. My first two debug statement displays the correct values, but the 3rd trying to loop through the dictionary items fails, so I can't run the 4th play. Can anybody suggect what I'm doing wrong?

### Inventory File - "inventory"

```
[Hosts]
host1 environment=dev
hots2 environment=test
```

### Code File - "deploy.yml"

```
    ---
    - name: Mount issue
      hosts: all
      gather_facts: false
      vars:
        nfs_hostname: server1
        nfs_mounts:
          - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive1", dest: /mnt/drive1 }
          - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive2", dest: /mnt/drive2 }
      tasks:
        - name: display environments
          debug:
            var: hostvars[ansible_host].environment
        - name: display mounts
          debug:
            var: nfs_mounts
        - name: display each mount
          debug:
            var: item
          with_items:
            - "{{ nfs_mounts }}"
        - name: mount
          mount:
            src: "{{ item.src }}"
            dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
          with_items:
            - "{{ nfs_mounts }}"
```

### Results

*Fails on "display each mount" 'ansible_host' is undefined*
e.g

Based on my `nfs_mounts` definition I want to be able to mount using the appropriate value for `environment` based on my inventory values

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory deploy.yml

PLAY [Mount issue] *********************************************************************************************************
 
TASK [display environments] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [hots2] => {
    "hostvars[ansible_host].environment": "test"
}
ok: [host1] => {
    "hostvars[ansible_host].environment": "dev"
}
TASK [display mounts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "nfs_mounts": [
        {
            "dest": "/mnt/drive1",
            "src": "/mnt/nas/dev/drive1"
        },
        {
            "dest": "/mnt/drive2",
            "src": "/mnt/nas/dev/drive2"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [hots2] => {
    "nfs_mounts": [
        {
            "dest": "/mnt/drive1",
            "src": "/mnt/nas/test/drive1"
        },
        {
            "dest": "/mnt/drive2",
            "src": "/mnt/nas/test/drive2"
        }
    ]
}
TASK [display each mount] **************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "[{'src': '/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive1', 'dest': '/mnt/drive1'}, {'src': '/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive2', 'dest': '/mnt/drive2'}]: 'ansible_host' is undefined"}
fatal: [hots2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "[{'src': '/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive1', 'dest': '/mnt/drive1'}, {'src': '/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive2', 'dest': '/mnt/drive2'}]: 'ansible_host' is undefined"}
 
PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hots2                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I also tried using `inventory_host` which provided the same result

Answer (score 1):

The variables set in inventory can be accessed for *that* host without having to use `hostvars`. We need to use `hostvars` when we have to fetch facts/variables from *other* hosts in the inventory.

So a simple inventory like:

```ini
[Hosts]
host1 port=80
host2 port=443
```

And a playbook like:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: port
```

Will yield the value of `port` for that host automatically. One thing to note is that `environment` is a [reserved variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) in Ansible, and it's better to avoid setting it ourselves.

So we can use a different variable, example:

```ini
[Hosts]
host1 env=dev
host2 env=test
```

Then use it in playbook:

```yaml
- name: Mount issue
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    nfs_mounts:
      - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ env }}/drive1", dest: /mnt/drive1 }
      - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ env }}/drive2", dest: /mnt/drive2 }

  tasks:
    - name: display each mount
      debug:
        var: item
      with_items: "{{ nfs_mounts }}"
```

Ansible provides for organizing inventory as different environments. Since you want to differentiate environments, refer [how to build inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Comment: The critical part of the reply was not to use environment as a variable name, all sorts of side-effects were created by me doing that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You are confusing `ansible_host` (i.e. an IP or fqdn which can be set for the host in your inventory if its `inventory_hostname` is an alias that does not resolve to an IP) and `inventory_hostname` (i.e. the name of the host in your inventory). As a long notation, your variable should be:

   ```yaml
   nfs_mounts:
     - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].environment }}/drive1", dest: /mnt/drive1 }
     - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].environment }}/drive2", dest: /mnt/drive2 }
   ```
2. You don't need that long notation as you are using the variable directly defined for the host in the play loop

   ```yaml
   nfs_mounts:
     - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ environment }}/drive1", dest: /mnt/drive1 }
     - { src: "/mnt/nas/{{ environment }}/drive2", dest: /mnt/drive2 }
   ```

This is the final example reported in @shshadri_c's answer with a complete playbook to test

Answer (score -2):

It looks like an Ansible bug - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16776#issuecomment-407416931

But you can with around with it using `set_fact`.

Instead of defining `nfs_mounts` in `vars`, define it with `set_fact`:

```
---
- name: Mount issue
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    nfs_hostname: server1
  tasks:
    - name: set fact
      set_fact:
        nfs_mounts:
          - {
              src: '/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive1',
              dest: /mnt/drive1,
            }
          - {
              src: '/mnt/nas/{{ hostvars[ansible_host].environment }}/drive2',
              dest: /mnt/drive2,
            }
    - name: display environments
      debug:
        var: hostvars[ansible_host].environment
    - name: display mounts
      debug:
        var: nfs_mounts
    - name: display each mount
      debug:
        var: item
      with_items:
        - "{{ nfs_mounts }}"
    - name: mount
      mount:
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ nfs_mounts }}"
```

Comment: There is absolutely no bug besides the fact OP is using `ansible_host` instead of `inventory_hostname` and that problem is still present in your answer. Moreover, this adds an unnecessary `set_fact` task.